# Transfer Recursive/Circular Excel Logic to SQL Syntax

Tags: sql, excel, google-sheets, psql

### Problem Description

I have a problem where I want to transfer some **Excel/GSheet Logic** to standard **SQL Syntax**:

- There are three conditions with booleans: `cond_1`, `cond_2`, `cond_3`
- The `final_flag` column should follow the same excel logic just in SQL
- The issue is that in Excel the first value in `M2` was statically/manually set to `False`

Example of hard coded value:

[image: Example of hard coded value]

- The subsequent cells `M3` etc were then calculated with some logic: `=if(L3,false,if(K3,false,or(J3,M2)))`

Formula to calculate final logic:

[image: Formula to calculate final logic]

### First Ideas

- The hard part is to reference to an already calculated cell (`or (J3,M2)`) in SQL with having the first cell being a hard coded value
- This seems to require a sort of recursive logic that is hard to replicate in SQL

Here's a link to sample data with the logic: [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FkKm9RTa8Z8NVn0A9ptJqYKve-nj-UJ1JL0HqD5GBDY/edit?usp=sharing)

If you have any hints or what syntax of SQL might be able to solve this, please let me know! Thanks :)

Comment: Including sample data and desired results *as text tables* in the question is a big help -- as is an explanation of what your logic should be doing.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: You don't really explain where the J's, K's, and L's come from.  If they are external will they be in a table when you translate to SQL?  What is it that gives M3 a relationship with M2?  In SQL you need to instantiate that through an ordering property, even if it's just a 1, 2, 3 sequence.  SQL data sets (tables and result sets) do not have intrinsic ordering properties. If you can answer those questions, then providing you with an answer should be relatively straightforward - maybe even without recursion.

Comment: Depends what you mean by standard SQL - there are lead and lag functions in SQL Server 2012 which may help https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9127/sql-server-window-functions-lead-and-lag/

Comment: I added the link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FkKm9RTa8Z8NVn0A9ptJqYKve-nj-UJ1JL0HqD5GBDY/edit?usp=sharing to the question, where you can see the formula and desired results :) I hope this helps a bit more to explain what I am trying to accomplish!

Answer (score 0):

I have created a recursive cte that works on MS SQL Server 2017 via [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com).

Here is my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Test(
row_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
cond_1 bit,
cond_2 bit,
cond_3 bit,
final_flag bit
);
-- I placed an initial false into the first row
INSERT INTO Test(cond_1, cond_2, cond_3, final_flag)
VALUES
(0, 0, 1, 0)
;

INSERT INTO Test(cond_1, cond_2, cond_3)
VALUES
(1, 0, 0),
(0, 1, 0),
(0, 0, 0),
(0, 0, 0),
(0, 0, 0),
(0, 0, 0),
(0, 0, 0),
(1, 0, 0),
(0, 0, 0),
(0, 0, 0),
(0, 0, 0),
(0, 0, 1),
(1, 0, 0),
(0, 1, 0),
(0, 0, 0),
(0, 0, 0),
(0, 0, 0),
(0, 0, 0),
(0, 0, 0),
(1, 0, 0),
(0, 0, 0),
(0, 0, 0),
(0, 0, 0);
```

#### Table:

[image: table]

#### Query:

```
WITH cte AS (
  -- anchor query
  SELECT row_ID, cond_1, cond_2, cond_3, final_flag
  FROM Test
  WHERE row_ID = 1

  UNION ALL
  -- recursive query
  SELECT This.row_ID, This.cond_1, This.cond_2, This.cond_3, 
         cast(case when This.cond_3|This.cond_2 = 1 then 0
                   else This.cond_1|Prev.final_flag
              end as bit) as final_flag
  FROM Test This, cte Prev
  WHERE This.row_id = Prev.row_id + 1
)
SELECT cond_1, cond_2, cond_3, final_flag FROM cte;
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- I added a `row_ID` column for the comparison to be easier. You can always exclude them on the output.
- You might have noticed that my final flag calculation is a bit different from yours. I simplified your formula `=if(L3,false,if(K3,false,or(J3,M2)))` to this `=IF(OR(K3,L3),FALSE,OR(M2,J3))` so I can use only 1 `case` statement, further simplifying the whole query.
- The result is **not written** to the table. Feel free to update the table based on the output.
- For more details, read about [recursive sql queries using ctes](https://haughtcodeworks.com/blog/software-development/recursive-sql-queries-using-ctes/). Recursive sql queries is very new to me and made it work just by reading that blog.